# Python ValueError: expected ':' after format specifier

Tags: python

I'm using a dict in python in an attempt to replace words in a string with whatever is in the dict. When I try to run my code, however, it prints out the error "ValueError: expected ':' after format specifier."  I have no idea where this error might be coming from. Does anyone with more pythonic wisdom have any suggestions for me? 
Thanks!

Here's an example of my code:

```
str = """{fruit}"""
dict = {"fruit":"pears"}
str.replace(**dict)
```

This should make str contain "pears".

**UPDATE**

I'm purposefully using the triple quoted strings - in my code I'm trying to do a replace with a multiline string, 
Also, my code is already using the .format method. I just decided to mix the words when translating it between my code to here. This is an updated version of my example code that isn't working.

```
my_dict = """{fruit}"""
dict = {"fruit":"pears"}
string.format(**my_dict)
```

**FINAL UPDATE**

Thanks for all of the answers I received below. I didn't do a good job of explaining my problem and decided to simplify it which simplified away my problem. I'm doing some meta programming so I was trying to replace within a C function definition and python was trying to use the "{" as a format identifier. I needed to use "{{" to get python to recognize the bracket as a char and not as some beginning to a format identifier.

Comment: Can you elaborate? This raises `TypeError: replace() takes no keyword arguments` here, as it should.

Comment: Shoot I am using the format function already. For some reason I decided to call it replace >.<

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use the `format()` function instead of `replace()`:

```
string = "{fruit}"
my_dict = {"fruit": "pears"}
print(string.format(**my_dict))
```

**Output**

```
pears
```

A couple of other things: you shouldn't use the Python keywords `str` and `dict` as variable names. I have changed your variable names for clarity.

Also, you were using a multi-line string with triple quotes for no particular reason, so I changed that too.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for answering - I just realized that I meant to say format instead of replace. I'm using the format function already.  Also I was using the triple quotes because in my larger application it is a multi-line string. This is all information I should have provided to begin with.  I'll go update my question to reflect this clarification.  And thanks for the correction on variable names!

Comment: If you are using `format` already then your code should work fine!

Comment: Hm, I'm still getting the ValueError: expected ':' after format specifier error. Could it be that some piece of code isn't correctly adding to the dictionary?

Comment: There must be something else incorrect in your code. My example works

Answer (score 2):

Another simple method to replace sentence with a dictionary. I hope you like the simplicity. Also look into this [Single Pass Multiple Replace](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/81330-single-pass-multiple-replace/)

```
import re

s = "node.js ruby python python3 python3.6"
d = {'python': 'python2.7', 'python3': 'python3.5', 'python3.6': 'python3.7'}

pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(d.keys()) + r')\b')
result = pattern.sub(lambda x: d[x.group()], s)

print result
```

This will match whole words only.

Comment: That's a very fragile way to do it. There is no delimiter, so 'pythonic' will become 'python3.3ic', and if any of the words in `word_mapping` is a prefix of another then either could be used for the replacement: `word_mapping = {'python': 'python2.7', 'python3': 'python3.5'}` could turn `python3` into either `python2.73` or `python3.5` and you won't know which.

Comment: Yes, you're right! I have edited my answer, now it will match whole words only!